# Flex 3 application done for higher resolution (1024*768 or more) not working in lesser resolution (800*600)

Tags: apache-flex, flex3, adobe, custom-component, screen-resolution

I have developed an application using adobe flex 3. There are many custom components in this application. I have developed this product assuming minimum screen resolution of 1024*768 and hence I hard coded widths of few Components.

But, I learnt that the client is using the product on a projector with resolution 800*600.

When I tried running the application on 800*600 resolution, I could not use the application as few screens are not seen completely.

I foresee that if make the application for 800*600, it will not look good on a bigger resolution.

I would like to know how I can tackle this problem with minimum effect? I am unable to decide if I have to redo most of the components with lesser resolution.

**[Edit]**

Based on the answers, to test, I have changed the width and height of a component to 100%. Basically this component is a `TitleWindow` with a `ControlBar` at the bottom. and is used for a `popup`. The problem I face is, the `ControlBar` is not seen. The application has `VerticalScrollBar` but still unable to scroll in the popup. On Vertical Scrolling the application is getting scrolled but not the popup.

Hope you understand my problem and can suggest a solution.

Thanks

Anji

Answer (score 1):

You just shouldn't use hardcoded sizes at all. Use `percentWidth`, `percentHeight` and layout constrains.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Yeah I could have used, but during development, I was in the impression that minimum resolution is 1024*768 and hardcoded values of width and height for few childrens in custom component.

Comment: +1 You use absolute width/height values, you are almost always welcoming trouble.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use percentage widths.  In ActionScript you can set the [percentWidth](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#percentWidth) and [percentHeight](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#percentHeight) properties on the component.  In MXML you can just specify the percentage sign in the width or height property, like this:

```
<mx:UIComponent width="100%" height="100%" />
```

Another option is to size and position your children in [updateDisplayList()](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/core/UIComponent.html#updateDisplayList%28%29) based on the size of the component.  The values passed into updateDisplayList() are the component's height and width, as defined by that component's parent.

Although MXML can mask it sometimes all components size and position their children in updateDisplayList() based on the size set by the parent.

Comment: @Anji you're going to have to show some code and/or some screenshots for more help . I can't direct you in a specific direction based on your updates.